# Getting hundreds of errors when running 'sudo yo meanjs'

Tags: phantomjs, yeoman, mean-stack, meanjs

I am attempting to work through the following tutorial: http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/mean-stack-tutorial-part-1-setup/
to teach my self MEAN stack development. All of the packages seem to be installed correctly as far as I can tell.

When I run 'sudo yo mean js' I get over 500 lines of errors and warnings (more than I can put in a post here). The following are the first hundred or so in hopes that someone can see the pattern and point me in the right direction.

Not sure if this is relevant but it probably takes around 10 to 15 minutes for 'sudo yo meanjs' to return these errors.

Much thanks in advance!

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd mean && npm install
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs@2.1.3: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Please update 'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt'
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: Grunt needs your help! See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1403.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.8.0 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global nodemon@1.9.0 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.3.0 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-inspector@0.10.2 should be installed with -g
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:256:25: note: previous definition is here
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:661:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:672:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'enum encoding' for 3rd argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: candidate function not viable: 2nd argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:676:12: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object> &&' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:214:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local' against 'MaybeLocal'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:326:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'S *' against 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'
  V8_INLINE Local(S* that)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:683:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Primitive *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:414:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Primitive>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Boolean *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:424:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Boolean>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::True(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Function *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1514:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Function>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(handle)->Get(kCallbackIndex)
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Object *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1632:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(handle->Get(NanNew(key)).As<v8::Object>());
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/christopherward/MeanStackTutorial/NorthwindNode/mean/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.1.0 bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.1.0 Exit status 1
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o.d.raw { dev: 16777218,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 19122429,
  size: 1318,
  blocks: 8,
  atime: Tue Feb 23 2016 12:32:42 GMT-0800 (PST),
  mtime: Tue Feb 23 2016 12:32:42 GMT-0800 (PST),
  ctime: Tue Feb 23 2016 12:32:42 GMT-0800 (PST),
  birthtime: Tue Feb 23 2016 12:32:42 GMT-0800 (PST) }
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o.d.raw { dev: 16777218,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 19122463,
  size: 1318,
  blocks: 8,
  atime: Tue Feb 23 2016 12:32:51 GMT-0800 (PST),
  mtime: Tue Feb 23 2016 12:32:51 GMT-0800 (PST),
  ctime: Tue Feb 23 2016 12:32:51 GMT-0800 (PST),
  birthtime: Tue Feb 23 2016 12:32:51 GMT-0800 (PST) }
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:
../../nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:256:25: note: previous definition is here
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:661:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:672:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'enum encoding' for 3rd argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: candidate function not viable: 2nd argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:
../../nan/nan.h:676:12: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object> &&' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:214:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local' against 'MaybeLocal'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:326:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'S *' against 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'
  V8_INLINE Local(S* that)
            ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:
../../nan/nan.h:683:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:7:
/Users/christopherward/.node-gyp/4.3.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Primitive *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

generator-meanjs is only compatible with lower versions of Node (0.12.10) and NPM as of now.

To get it resolved, you have to downgrade your node, npm and meanjs generator versions. There is no implementation of sub generators such as CRUD or Vertical modules in latest version of generator-meanjs.

If you have latest version of node installed - then you will end up with tons of errors. If you really want to use mean js generators I recommend you to downgrade your node version. (I prefer nvm - node version manager).

Check your generator version - `npm view generator­meanjs versions` and downgrade to 0.12.x version of generator.

The versions should be,

**Node - 0.12.x**
**Npm - 2.x**
**generator-meanjs - 0.12.x**

Once you are done, there will be no problem to use the fabulous MEAN stack generator.